# Otp application:stop(..) kills all spawned processes, not just spawn_linked ones?

Tags: erlang

I've set up a simple test-case at https://github.com/bvdeenen/otp_super_nukes_all that shows that an otp application:stop() actually kills **all** spawned processes by its children, even the ones that are **not linked**.

The test-case consists of one gen_server (registered as par) spawning a plain erlang process (registered as par_worker) and a gen_server (registered as reg_child), which also spawns a plain erlang process (registered as child_worker). Calling application:stop(test_app) does a normal termination on the 'par' gen_server, but an exit(kill) on all others!

Is this nominal behaviour? If so, where is it documented, and can I disable it? I want the processes I spawn from my gen_server (not link), to stay alive when the application terminates.

Thanks

Bart van Deenen

Answer (score 5):

The [application](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#stop-1) manual says (for the stop/1 function):

```
Last, the application master itself terminates. Note that all processes with the
application master as group leader, i.e. processes spawned from a process belonging
to the application, thus are terminated as well.
```

So I guess you cant modify this behavior.

**EDIT**: You might be able to change the group_leader of the started process with group_leader(GroupLeader, Pid) -> true (see: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#group_leader-2). Changing the group_leader might allow you to avoid killing your process when the application ends.

Comment: Thans, I found out the group_leader also. It was not clear to me but I learned a lot! It works:   `group_leader( whereis(init), Pid)`, causes my processes to stay alive. I really need to, for complex reasons having to do with distributed application upgrades in a live system.

Comment: Great, you can answer your own question then, or if this one was the exact solution/answer, mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

I made that mistakes too, and found out it must happen.

If parent process dies, all children process dies no matter what it is registered or not.

If this does not happen, we have to track all up-and-running processes and figure out which is orphaned and which is not. you can guess how difficult it would be. You can think of unix ppid and pid. if you kill ppid, all children dies too. This, I think this must happen.

If you want to have processes independent from your application, you can send a messageto other application to start processes.

```
other_application_module:start_process(ProcessInfo).
```

Comment: I need to do this, because I actually clone spawned processes on another node in a distributed application. Thanks for the answer.